# mysql number wildcard

Tags: mysql, numbers, coordinates, wildcard

I currently have a table in mysql db with four columns : State, City, Latitude, Longitude.
My Latitude and Longitude columns are of type float(10,6).
I am looking to implement a MySQL Query where I can search for similar Latitude Longitude entries, For example, I want to implement something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `Latitude` LIKE '41.wxyz' and 'Longitude' LIKE '-87.wxyz'
```

where wxyz can be any digits. I want to do this so I can return all cities in close proximity to any given arbitrary coordinates. can any one help me out?

**SOLUTION/UPDATE**
I was unable to get my application to do what I wanted with the answers provided below! although I do appreciate everyones' input; I was able to expand my SQL query knowledge. In order to get my application to find nearby locations with respect to a latitude and longitude pair I used Haversine formula. As detailed in this google maps article. https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

where lat and lng are columns in a mysql table. and 37 and -122 are the coordinates to which you wish to find other nearby coordinates, in your table. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by this as well:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE (`Latitude` between 41.0 and 42.0) and ('Longitude' between -87.0 and -88.0)
```

Try this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [ROUND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function, e.g. -

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable`
  WHERE ROUND(Latitude, 0) = 41 AND ROUND(Longitude, 0) = -87
```